# Xcode assertion while calling storyboard view controller programmatically

Tags: xcode, ios6

I am connecting two storyboard view controllers programmatically. I am getting the following assertion:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[FullGalleryViewController loadView], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UICollectionViewController.m:104
```

My code is as follows:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
FullScreenViewController *myVC = (FullScreenViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FullScreenViewControllerId"];
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have set the storyboard id to be `FullScreenViewControllerId`. I don't understand where am I going wrong.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Which line causes the assertion?

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate FullScreenViewController and assertion failure is in FullGalleryViewController. It's not the same class.